# Switching between realms (iOS / Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm

I was trying to log in or register a user and connect them to an existing realm. Then, depending on the info stored in that realm, I may need them to instead connect to a different realm.

Is it not possible to try! Realm with a different configuration after it is initially configured? Is it discouraged? Does it need to be done outside of the initial DispatchQueue?

Here is the code:

```
SyncUser.logIn(with: usernameCredentials, server: URL(string: "http://11.22.333.0:9080")!) {
     user, error in
     guard let user = user else {
         fatalError(String(describing: error))
     }

     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         let configuration = Realm.Configuration(
             syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: URL(string: "realm://11.22.333.0:9080/ab56realmURL/NameOfRealm1")!)
         )
         self.realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)

         if (someCheckOfData in realm) {
              let configuration2 = Realm.Configuration(
                  syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: URL(string: "realm://11.22.333.0:9080/ab56realmURL/NameOfRealm2")!)
              )
              self.realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration2)
         }
      }
}
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not discouraged. All you're doing here is creating 2 discrete copies of `Configuration`, which will then subsequently be creating 2 separate Realm instances on your server.

The two will be completely separate, so there's no chance of causing an exception by incorrectly changing the configuration after it was used to create an initial `Realm` instance.

One thing we do recommend though is not holding onto specific Realm references like that though. They are not thread safe, and GCD isn't guaranteed to execute the same queues on the same threads, so you may be setting yourself up for a future exception.

If this is going to be your primary Realm, it's usually recommended to set that `Configuration` as the default Realm one. Otherwise, since `Configuration` is thread-safe (Assuming you don't modify it later), you can hold onto that, and use it to `try! Realm(configuruation:)` whenever you actually need to use Realm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've made progress toward my goal with this code. Which part of it is holding onto a specific Realm reference? What do you mean by the primary Realm set to default configuration? I only try! Realm(configuration:) when the user first logs in/signs up or when I need to switch them to a different Realm. After that I just use try! itemName.realm?.write { to make changes and I receive updates with a notificationToken for any changes in the Realm they're connected to. Once I set self.realm to configuration2, the realm I was initially connected to is overwritten, right?

Comment: @RanLearns No worries! If this solved your question, please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer. :) When you add a property to your class called `realm` and you manually set `self.realm = realm`, that's what I meant by hanging onto a reference. By primary Realm, I meant if you don't want to use `Realm(configuration:)` every time, you can set `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration` to be the Realm that is returned when you call `Realm()`.

Comment: Ah okay! No, it won't be overwritten. It will exist as a separate entry in your user's account.